# Java - Python - Is there an equivalent of java's Character.getNumericValue in Python?

Tags: java, python

I have a very simple `java` class that I am trying to port to `Python`, but I'm stuck on the line:

```
int value = Character.getNumericValue(character);
```

I have found [this](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/corejava/Characters/getNumericValue.html) example, but I don't understand how `Character.getNumericValue(character)` could return `10` (since the ASCII value is `65` for instance).

Without understanding this line, it's difficult to port it.

Comment: Did you read the documentation to find out what it actually does? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Character.getNumericValue()` returns `10` for `A` because it is digit in number systems with bases beyond the decimal system (such as hexadecimal, all the way up to 35-base):

```
>>> int('A', 36)
10
>>> int('Z', 36)
35
```

From the [`Character.getNumericValue()` documenation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29):

> The letters A-Z in their uppercase (`'\u0041'` through `'\u005A'`), lowercase (`'\u0061'` through `'\u007A'`), and full width variant (`'\uFF21'` through `'\uFF3A'` and `'\uFF41'` through `'\uFF5A'`) forms have numeric values from 10 through 35. This is independent of the Unicode specification, which does not assign numeric values to these `char` values.

There is no direct Python equivalent; `Character.getNumericValue()` also interprets roman numerals, for example, you'd have to code such mappings yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single ready-made Python function that's equivalent, but I think two functions combined cover the whole range. For ASCII characters 0..9 and A..Z, `int()` with a proper base argument (36) suffices. For getting the numeric value of a unicode code point, there's [unicodedata.numeric](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.numeric), discounting the fact that it returns a float.